# CUDA: Can allocate matrix once use in multi kernel?

Tags: c++, matrix, cuda

I have a question that is:
If i allocate 1 matrix 2D and i memcpy it into GPU and i have 2 kernel using the same that matrix, is it possible using which i don't memcpy that matrix again for kernel 2?
And if it auto memcpy that matrix again for kernel 2, Does it take the time to auto memcpy it again ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to transfer data from host to device twice, if you want to use it in 2 kernels.  Once you transfer it, it is in GPU memory and will stay there until your program terminates  (or you explicitly deallocate it using e.g. `cudaFree`).

Just pass the pointer to the region/matrix to both kernels.  If the first kernel modifies the data and the second kernel runs later (after the first kernel finishes), the second kernel will see the modified data.